# Why it is showing "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote"?

Tags: java, string, jsp

The line at message.setContent() where I am trying to put a HTML code as string argument is showing error as "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote". Please help me find out why it is showing like that.

```
try {
      // Create a default MimeMessage object.
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
      MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
      %>

<% 

      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));


      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                               new InternetAddress(to));

      message.setSubject("Thank you for using our service");



      message.setContent("<table><tr><td>Full Name</td><td><%= name %></td></tr><tr><td>Address</td><td><%= Addr %></td></tr><tr><td>Age</td><td><%= age %></td></tr><tr><td>Qualification</td><td><%= Qual %></td></tr><tr><td>Percentage</td><td><%= Persent %></td></tr><tr><td>Year of Passout</td><td><%= Year %></td></tr></table>",
"text/html");


      Transport.send(message);
      result = "Sent message successfully....";
   } catch (MessagingException mex) {
      mex.printStackTrace();
      result = "Error: unable to send message....";
   }
```

Comment: Try message.setContent(Message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: message.setContent("..........

Comment: I'm not sure <%= is legal in internal code. JSP compiler can be confused

Comment: @JacekCz My guess is when JSP compiler encounter the `%>` in the string literal, it simply treat it is the end of the JSP code block

Comment: Please suggest me how should I approach for that? What alternative do I have?

Comment: Code like this (sending email) really doesn't belong in a JSP (apart from the fact that code in JSP is a bad idea in general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output statement <%=name%> on a jsp, when compiled produces the output:

```
out.print(name);
```

Now if you are trying inside your string to append the **name** variable you should just use:

```
message.setContent("<table><tr><td>Full Name</td><td>"+name+"</td></tr>.....","text/html");
```

Dont forget that you have to define somewhere the **name** variable like this:

```
<%String name = request.getParameter("name");%>
```

Or something like this....

...Of course this is not how you should be using JSPs. The use of scriptlets should be strongly avoided. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

Comment: Thank you @MaVRoSCy!!! It worked fine. It is just for my testing purpose so i did it as per my limited knowledge to make it very simple. I will definitely try to avoid adding excess java code in JSP in my next codes. Thanks alot